# How to create tables in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

i want that if table do not exist in database then they should be automatically created but they should not override the existing data or drop tables.

i have used in properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

i have tried "none" option as well.

my **entityManager**

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(R.Blueberry_PACKAGE);
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("blueberryPersistenceUnit");
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getObject();
```

**jpaVendor**

```
@Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }
```

Comment: Your properties are useless as you are overriding the auto configure features of Spring Boot. Why aren't you simply using the auto config feature? Instead of adding it to the `application.properties` you will need to add it to the list of `jpaProperties` of course without the `spring.jpa.properties` prefix.

Comment: M.Deinum thanks for your reply. i dont want to have auto configuration for some other valid and verified reasons... though you are right with auto configuration. Any other option you think would work in my case ?